# Using DataTables and extend excelHtml5 via JavaScript, how can I insert an image in the "title" property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

[Excel Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPs7D.png)

[Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCVdB.png)

```
buttons: [ 
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<h2>EXPORT TO EXCEL</h2>', //'Export to Excel',
                    //orientation: 'landscape',
                    //pageSize: '11x17', 
                    title: 'Hello',
                    messageTop: function () {

                        var today = new Date();
```

I am using Datatables and the excelHtml5 button extension via Javascript & jQuery. You will see in the beginning of the code the text "Hello" in the title property. I am also using messageTop, customize, and createEmptyCells for other formatting purposes. In the attachment you will see the resulting "Hello" text circled in red.

I need to insert a legend image (.png) on the top. Is there any way to do this? Alternatively, if I cannot get in image in the title property I could format each cell of the title to look like the legend but I am not sure how to do this in the title property?

I was thinking along the lines of...

```
title: function() {
                        var imgProcessMap = $("#imgProcessMap");
                        return imgProcessMap;
                    },
```

...but this returns the object.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this like one week, I found this article and it was so useful for me.
Source: https://quo.wtf/posts/datatable_howto_export_excel_with_image/

You need to modify `buttons.html5.js`, and change `xlsx` and `excelStrings` variables basic structure to a new one. Then, use JQuery Datatables customize to send the image.

But, it doesn't work. I realize you have to modify `_addToZip` function in `buttons.html5.js` to add the image with jszip, and an aditional validation.

Here's full `_addToZip` code.

```
function _addToZip( zip, obj ) {
    if ( _ieExcel === undefined ) {
        // Detect if we are dealing with IE's _awful_ serialiser by seeing if it
        // drop attributes
        _ieExcel = _serialiser
            .serializeToString(
                ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString( excelStrings['xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml'], 'text/xml' )
            )
            .indexOf( 'xmlns:r' ) === -1;
    }

    $.each( obj, function ( name, val ) {
        if ( $.isPlainObject( val ) ) {
            var newDir = zip.folder( name );
            _addToZip( newDir, val );
        }
        else if (!$.isXMLDoc(val)){
            var newDir = zip.folder(name);
            newDir.file(val[0].name, val[0].data, {base64: true});
        }
        else {
            if ( _ieExcel ) {
                // IE's XML serialiser will drop some name space attributes from
                // from the root node, so we need to save them. Do this by
                // replacing the namespace nodes with a regular attribute that
                // we convert back when serialised. Edge does not have this
                // issue
                var worksheet = val.childNodes[0];
                var i, ien;
                var attrs = [];

                for ( i=worksheet.attributes.length-1 ; i>=0 ; i-- ) {
                    var attrName = worksheet.attributes[i].nodeName;
                    var attrValue = worksheet.attributes[i].nodeValue;

                    if ( attrName.indexOf( ':' ) !== -1 ) {
                        attrs.push( { name: attrName, value: attrValue } );

                        worksheet.removeAttribute( attrName );
                    }
                }

                for ( i=0, ien=attrs.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                    var attr = val.createAttribute( attrs[i].name.replace( ':', '_dt_b_namespace_token_' ) );
                    attr.value = attrs[i].value;
                    worksheet.setAttributeNode( attr );
                }
            }

            var str = _serialiser.serializeToString(val);

            // Fix IE's XML
            if ( _ieExcel ) {
                // IE doesn't include the XML declaration
                if ( str.indexOf( '<?xml' ) === -1 ) {
                    str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+str;
                }

                // Return namespace attributes to being as such
                str = str.replace( /_dt_b_namespace_token_/g, ':' );

                // Remove testing name space that IE puts into the space preserve attr
                str = str.replace( /xmlns:NS[\d]+="" NS[\d]+:/g, '' );
            }

            // Safari, IE and Edge will put empty name space attributes onto
            // various elements making them useless. This strips them out
            str = str.replace( /<([^<>]*?) xmlns=""([^<>]*?)>/g, '<$1 $2>' );

            zip.file( name, str );
        }
    } );
}
```

Sorry for my english, hope this helps.